# Ubuntu one in Lubuntu and Xubuntu

Tags: 13.04, ubuntu-one, xubuntu, lubuntu

I have an old computer running Ubuntu 13.04 and want to speed it up by using Lubuntu or Xubuntu.  Will ubuntu one work on these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Note: [Ubuntu One is now depreciated](http://blog.canonical.com/2014/04/02/shutting-down-ubuntu-one-file-services/) so this question and answer are no longer relevant]

Yes

Simply open Terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and then type in

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

In Lubuntu, all you need to do is go to Application Menu > System Settings (?) > Ubuntu One. I think it is the same/very similar in Xubuntu 13.10 and earlier, in Xubuntu 14.04 (with Whisker Menu) just type in 'Ubuntu One'.

In any case, you can always access the web version of Ubuntu One.